# Arduino: Splitting a string AND randomly selecting tokens

Tags: string, split, arduino, token, strtok

I built a program in Processing that pseudorandomly generates imperative sentences. The program combines a randomly selected verb, possessive adjective, and noun in order to display a final sentence.
Here is a summarized version of the program:

```
void sentence() {
  String VerbList = "abide accelerate accept accomplish achieve acquire acted etc.”;
  String[] Verbs = VerbList.split("\\s");
  String PossessiveAdjectiveList =  "my your his her its our their";
  String [] PossessiveAdjectives = PossessiveAdjectiveList.split("\\s");
  String NounList = "account achiever acoustics act action activity actor etc.”;
  String[] Nouns = NounList.split("\\s");

  int verb = int(random(Verbs.length));
  int possessiveAdjective = int(random(PossessiveAdjectives.length));
  int noun = int(random(Nouns.length));

  String Sentence = Verbs[verb]+" "+PossessiveAdjectives[possessiveAdjective]+" "+Nouns[noun];
  println(Sentence);
```

Upon moving the code to the Arduino IDE, I immediately discovered the absence of a string.split function. I understand that I can turn a string into tokens using strtok; however, I am not sure how to select individual tokens through randomly generated integers. Should I be trying to use strtok? Here is my code thus far:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_MCP23017.h>
#include <Adafruit_RGBLCDShield.h>
Adafruit_RGBLCDShield lcd = Adafruit_RGBLCDShield();
#define WHITE 0x7

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.setBacklight(WHITE);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  sentence();
}

void sentence() {
  char VerbList[] = "abide accelerate accept accomplish achieve acquire acted etc.";
  char* Verbs = strtok(VerbList, " ");
  char PossessiveAdjectiveList[] =  "my your his her its our their";
  char* PossessiveAdjectives = strtok(PossessiveAdjectiveList, " ");
  char NounList[] = "account achiever acoustics act action activity actor etc.";
  char* Nouns = strtok(NounList, " ");
  //int verb = int(random(Verbs.length));
  //int verb = Verbs.substring(random(Verbs.length));
  //int possessiveAdjective = int(random(PossessiveAdjectives.length));
  //int noun = int(random(Nouns.length));
  //String Sentence = Verbs[verb]+" "+PossessiveAdjectives[possessiveAdjective]+" "+Nouns[noun];
  //lcd.print(Sentence);
}

uint8_t i=0;
void loop() {
  uint8_t buttons = lcd.readButtons();
  if (buttons) {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    if (buttons & BUTTON_SELECT) {
      sentence();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing much research, I have found a decent answer to my problem.
This code splits the verb, noun, and possessive adjective strings into tokens, and then selects a token from each string based on random integers. These tokens are then added up to form an imperative sentence. The final sentence is displayed on a 16X2 character LCD shield.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_MCP23017.h>
#include <Adafruit_RGBLCDShield.h>
Adafruit_RGBLCDShield lcd = Adafruit_RGBLCDShield();
#define MAX_STRING_LEN  1000

char *Verbs = "abide accelerate accept accomplish achieve";
char *PossessiveAdjectives = "my your his her its our their";
char *Nouns = "account achiever acoustics act action activity";
char *p, *i;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);

  int verbCount = 0,vc;
  int adjectiveCount = 0,ac;
  int nounCount = 0,nc;

  for(vc=0;vc<strlen(Verbs);vc++){
    if(Verbs[vc] == ' ')
      verbCount++;
  }
  for(ac=0;ac<strlen(PossessiveAdjectives);ac++){
    if(PossessiveAdjectives[ac] == ' ')
      adjectiveCount++;
  }
  for(nc=0;nc<strlen(Nouns);nc++){
    if(Nouns[nc] == ' ')
      nounCount++;
  }

  int randVerb = random(1,verbCount+2);
  int randPossessiveAdjective = random(1,adjectiveCount+2);
  int randNoun = random(1,nounCount+2);

  String Verb = subStr(Verbs, " ", randVerb);
  String PossessiveAdjective = subStr(PossessiveAdjectives, " ", randPossessiveAdjective);
  String Noun = subStr(Nouns, " ", randNoun);

  String ImperativeSentence = Verb+" "+PossessiveAdjective+" "+Noun;

  if(Verb.length()+PossessiveAdjective.length()+Noun.length()+2 > 16) {
    if(Verb.length()+PossessiveAdjective.length()+1 > 16) {
      if(Verb.length() > 16) {
        setup;
      } 
      else {
        lcd.print(Verb);
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(PossessiveAdjective);
        lcd.print(" ");
        lcd.print(Noun);
      }
    }
    else {
      lcd.print(Verb);
      lcd.print(" ");
      lcd.print(PossessiveAdjective);
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print(Noun);
    }
  }
  else {
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print(ImperativeSentence);
  }

  Serial.println(ImperativeSentence);
}

uint8_t a=0;
void loop() {
  uint8_t buttons = lcd.readButtons();
  if (buttons) {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    if (buttons & BUTTON_SELECT) {
      setup();
    }
  }
}

char* subStr (char* str, char *delim, int index) {
  char *act, *sub, *ptr;
  static char copy[MAX_STRING_LEN];
  int i;

  strcpy(copy, str);

  for (i = 1, act = copy; i <= index; i++, act = NULL) {
    sub = strtok_r(act, delim, &ptr);
    if (sub == NULL) break;
  }
  return sub;

}
```

This is clearly a work in progress. I still need to store a word bank on an SD card, and further simplify the code. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.